# count a variable y for every variable x in a DataFrame and also add the relative frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[55218],[55218],[55218],[55222]], "B": [[0],[0],[2],[1]]})
```

I want count every 0, 1 or 2 for 55218 in "A" and give the relative frequency back

My expected output is:

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[55218],[55218],[55218],[55222]],"B": [[0], [0], [2], [1]],"Count": [[2], [2], [1], [1]], "rel_frequ": [[0.67], [0.67], [0.33], [1]] })
```

Comment: I think you need `df['count'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['A'].transform('size')`

Comment: How working solution?

Comment: i think it works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and then divide column by mapped frequencies of `A` by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['A'].transform('size')
df['rel_frequ'] = df['Count'].div(df['A'].map(df['A'].value_counts()))
print (df)
       A  B  Count  rel_frequ
0  55218  0      2   0.666667
1  55218  0      2   0.666667
2  55218  2      1   0.333333
3  55222  1      1   1.000000
```